# Can't Get the url in the Should over overriding webview

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I am developing an android app, which has a webview in it..

The URL is https://www.facebook.com/ when the post is clicked in the webview the post URL is not getting in should overidding url but webview is redirecting the facebook to that particular post what is the problem the url should be in the shouldoverriding method of the webviewclient

```
Here I am Setting the Custom WebView Client 

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());

public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String str) {
            Log.e("urltop", str + " ==top");
            String str3 = "youtube";
            if (!str.contains("market://")) {
                if (!str.contains("mailto:") && !str.contains("play.google") && !str.contains("tel:") && !str.contains("intent:") && !str.contains("vid:") && !str.contains(str3) && !str.contains("fb-messenger://")) {
                    if (!str.contains("whatsapp://")) {
                        if (str.contains("m.me")) {
                            Log.e("urlm.me", str);
                            return true;
                        } else if (str.contains("jpg")) {
                            Log.e("urljpg", str);
                            return true;
                        }
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        Log.e("url", str);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should use the solution given by @JackTurky..That will surely do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.equals("YOURLINK")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), YourActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true; // Handle By application itself
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You... It helped me.. :)  .... I just had to edit getContext() to MainActivity.this  and the rest worked!

Comment: Just change the return type from false to true when u want to take the control. From doc: `If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles the url`

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to check and use [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).

By using WebViewClient, you can monior any action user makes with WebView. Now, as you want to detect URL click and want to start new activity based on it, check: [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).

Check [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) page for the WebViewClient example.